# How to make javax validation only display one error message

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Say I have validation on a field like this:

```
@NotEmpty
@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0)
private String code;
```

Using Spring MVC and Hibernate validation currently I get both messages if I leave the form field blank. Is there a way to only display the `@NotEmpty` message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick to the Bean Validation Specification you need to use a group sequence. Only a groups sequence guarantees an ordered constraint evaluation which stops on the first error. Something like:

```
@GroupSequence({ First.class, Second.class })
public class MyBean {
   @NotEmpty(groups = First.class)
   @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, groups = Second.class)
   private String code;
}
```

Comment: If validating just using the default group sequence and getting "javax.validation.GroupDefinitionException: MyBean must be part of the redefined default group sequence"
make sure to include the bean in the @GroupSequence, i.e.: @GroupSequence({ First.class, Second.class, MyBean.class }).

Comment: Simple yet efficient!